# C# comparar dos archivos por sus propiedades

Tags: c#, file

Necesito comparar dos fichero de texto por sus propiedades en C#, y no por su contenido. Por ejemplo, por fecha de creación y por fecha de modificación.
He conseguido compararlo por el contenido, dejo aquí el código:

```
private bool FileCompare(string file1, string file2)
{
     int file1byte;
     int file2byte;
     FileStream fs1;
     FileStream fs2;

     if (file1 == file2)
     {
          return true;
     }

     fs1 = new FileStream(file1, FileMode.Open);
     fs2 = new FileStream(file2, FileMode.Open);

     if (fs1.Length != fs2.Length)
     {
          // Close the file
          fs1.Close();
          fs2.Close();

          return false;
     }

     do 
     {
          // Read one byte from each file.
          file1byte = fs1.ReadByte();
          file2byte = fs2.ReadByte();
     }
     while ((file1byte == file2byte) && (file1byte != -1));

     fs1.Close();
     fs2.Close();

     return ((file1byte - file2byte) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas,

Debes crear un objeto tipo `DateTime` si quieres capturar alguna de las fechas que indicas y usar un método de la clase `File` u otro. Por ejemplo, para los que comentas sería así:

Capturar fecha de última modificación:

```
DateTime lastModif = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName);
DateTime lastModif2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName2);
```

Capturar fecha de creación:

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);
DateTime creationTime2 = File.GetCreationTime(fileName2);
```

Espero que te sirvan de ayuda. 
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la información que requieres debes hacer uso de la clase [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Te pongo un ejemplo para obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\prueba.txt");
DateTime fechaCreacion = fi.CreationTime;
```